# Is there a way to insert stylesheet with variable values in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I insert `<style>` to the DOM in a ReactJS project where the values of the stylesheet are dynamic coming from the database.

I have the following simplified scenario:

```
<button class="buy-now-button">Buy now</button>
```

**Note**: I have no access to modify the HTML or JSX element, the solution needs to be CSS only, and based on the class name that the button has.

I want to be able to add CSS properties like background, color, border to element with CSS class name `.buy-now-button`

What I need in terms of the stylesheet is:

```
<style>
  .buy-now-button {
      color: button.color; // where button.color value comes from DB
      background: button.background; // where button.background value comes from DB
  }
</style>
```

And then, that style should be inserted in the DOM.

Does ReactJS offer a mechanism to insert styles to the DOM? How could I solve this use case?

Many thanks

Comment: I only have two options but since they both rely on you being able to change the component they're moot. And you wouldn't be able to use Webpack to do this since you're going to be building the app and then accessing the DB from an endpoint at which point WP's job is done, so that's no use either. Another user may have a bespoke answer, but the answer is probably no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This whole thing is certainly an antipattern, as any time you are doing any sort of direct DOM manipulation with React you are abusing the way in which it is supposed to be used, but you could inject a `<style>` block a single time with the colors desired:

```js
function injectStylesheet() {
  const ss = document.createElement('style')
  ss.innerText = 'body { background-color: pink; }';
  document.head.append(ss);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="injectStylesheet()">add stylesheet</button>
```

While you could instead change the colors directly by finding the element and updating its `style` attribute, you would have to do this on every render, which is just a needless performance hit.

Comment: yes, @alexander-nied you are a genius, that solution can totally work! just a nice elegant plain vanilla js.  I will make the function accept parameters and based on that create dynamic styles. thank you

Comment: @Matt - glad to hear this will work for you-- hopefully in the near future you can work out a solution where you don't need something like this :) Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use a CDN to download a css file?

You wouldn't need to even do this within any React code. You could simply include the following in your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SOME-CDN-URL" />
```

Comment: thanks, @mark-williams but in your solution, the CSS still needs to be dynamically generated no?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the issue. Are you saying that the properties will vary based on things that are beyond the bounds of CSS class names? Can you give an example of what these variances might be?

Comment: Hi @mark-williams, yes the values of the css properties are given by the DB API call, and based on those values I need to generate a stylesheet with those dynamic values. I believe the solution is just plain javascript, creating a Style element and then injecting directly to the DOM